# error when installing sql server on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mssql

I am trying to install sql server on ubuntu 20.04 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16). In my understanding I don't have to install docker to run sql server on ubuntu 20.04. When executing

```
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
```

I get the error

```
        Reason: 0x00000001
     Signal: SIGABRT - Aborted (6)
      Stack:
             IP               Function
             ---------------- --------------------------------------
             0000559c4af150c1 std::__1::bad_function_call::~bad_function_call()+0x1b431
             0000559c4af14a86 std::__1::bad_function_call::~bad_function_call()+0x1adf6
             0000559c4af1400f std::__1::bad_function_call::~bad_function_call()+0x1a37f
             00007feb8a42f090 killpg+0x40
             00007feb8a42f00b gsignal+0xcb
             00007feb8a40e859 abort+0x12b
             0000559c4aea271b std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::str() const+0x7cbb
             0000559c4af3fe8a std::__1::bad_function_call::~bad_function_call()+0x461fa
```

I checked the requirements as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-ver16#system).

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Just to confirm, you've installed the SQL packages per the procedure and no errors were generated? And you're running an instance of Ubuntu 20.04 that has at least 2 GB of available memory, correct?